# Is it possible to reuse flexform field definitions using EXT:flux?

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

I'm new to the fedext-universe. By now, I've created a set of content elements, and they work fine.

There is one drawback though: One set of content elements has some fields in common, and these fields are rather complicated. Usually, I'd move their definition to a partial, but that isn't possible in flux forms. The [beginners guide](https://fedext.net/overview/beginners-guide.html) states

> Flux templates can use Layouts and
>   Partials - but a Flux form cannot
>   be split into Partial templates.

Is there any way to avoid redefining these fields over and over again? Among other things, I've tried to use the `<vhs:render.inline>` viewhelper along with a custom viewhelper, returning the fluid-definition of the fields, but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flux 7.0 will bring the option to place fields and sheets into Partial templates - if you are currently in a development project, I recommend trying it out from the `development` branches on Github:

https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/tree/development

Flux 7.0 also will bring the option to create PHP classes which for example create ready-made sheets with a bunch of fields - such a class would be ideal to reuse, simply requiring one PHP class and one Fluid ViewHelper. Such an approach would be more efficient when your forms are rendered, but of course is much more technically demanding than a Partial template.

EDIT: though not yet documented, creating custom sheets involves two simple steps: 1) create a subclass of `FluidTYPO3\Flux\Form\Container\Sheet` and a subclass of `FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers\Form\SheetViewHelper` - then include your namespace in the template, use your own ViewHelper instead of a `flux:form.sheet` (and add additional fields if you need them) and then inside the `Sheet` object, use the `$this->createField()` method from within object initialization, to automatically add any number of fields with predefined names, labels etc.

Comment: Nice, partials just work when using the dev branch :-) I'll try custom sheets later, when needed.